# Vue not installing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When I install Vue.js with Laravel framework, it doesn't create asset folder nor does it change app.js file inside asset folder. I used `Npm install` and then `npm run watch`, but when I navigate my self to the resource folder, it stays the same and I can locate Vue in package.json file. Why?

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel version 6.0.4

Comment: did you used `composer require laravel/ui --dev` ?

Comment: No I didn't, why?

Comment: I am answering with the steps please follow and then let me know if it works or give error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please run these commands in your terminal-

1. `composer require laravel/ui --dev`
2. `php artisan ui vue`
3. `php artisan ui vue --auth`
4. `npm install`
5. `npm run dev`
6. `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

use these commands

```
1:composer require laravel/ui --dev
2:php artisan ui vue
3:php artisan ui vue --auth
4:npm install
5:npm run dev
php artisan serve
```

Note: you can use Either 2 or 3.